# How to see if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to see if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}$$
converges or not.

I start with $$α_{n}=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}=$$
$$\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}=$$
$$\frac{n+1-n}{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}=$$
$$\frac{1}{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}.$$

And here I am stuck. How can I tell if $α_{n}$ converges or not?

In my textbook, it says that the last equation is $\leq\frac{1}{2n^{\frac{3}{2}}} $

But I cannot understand how or why it gets to that result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have

$$\frac{1}{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}\le \frac{1}{n(\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n})}=\frac1{2n^{3/2}}$$
so apparently there is a typo in your textbook.

Comment: Actually, I made that typo

Answer (score 1):

look at this please we have $$\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n+1}+n\cdot n^{1/2}}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)^{1/2}+n^{3/2}}\le \frac{1}{2n^{3/2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $b_n = \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} $as auxillary series and use comparison test

Answer (score -1):

Because $\sqrt{n+1}>\sqrt n$ in the range of $n$, $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n > 2\sqrt n$
and therefore the ratio is $\le \frac{1}{2n^{3/2}} = \zeta(3/2)/2$, where the
Riemann zeta function has a pole at 1 but is converging for larger values.

Comment: You should fix this part: "therefore the ratio is $\leq \frac{1}{2n^{3/2}} = \zeta(3/2)/2$". You have a constant equaling some expression of $n$.