# Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}$$
Does this series converge or diverge?

I tried all the tests like ratio test, Raabe's test, logarithmic test, comparison test but in vain. In ratio test I got the limit as $1$, so can't do anything with that. Can anybody give some hints?

Thank you!

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1101555, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2464657

Comment: All duplicates were found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%2B1%7D-%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D%7D%7Bn%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Can anybody give some hints?

**Hint**

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}\color{blue}{\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}}=\frac{1}{n\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)} \le \frac{1}{2n\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks. After that $p$- test and comparison will show that the given series is convergent, right?

Comment: Yes, well done!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes! We can then use the fact that a p-harmonic series converges for p>1 (proof is done using cauchy condensation test)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Write $$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{n}=\frac{1}{n(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}$$

Comment: Since my answer was/is right, Martin.

Comment: You should vote to close as a duplicate, instead of answering the same question again. It took me less than 2 minutes to find 3 identical questions – how much time did you invest?